# How to get just the ID from this._id when this._id returns an object?

Tags: meteor

I'm doing the newbie tutorial 'simple-todo' and noticed that once I added security in step 9, I was no longer able to delete tasks created before that.

The issue is that my remove method is checking to make sure that the ID it receives is a string, and the to-do tasks that were made earlier via the console return an object when I use this_.id.

In other words:
Tasks created via the terminal, this._id -> ObjectId("57a128afbe5fd7e7ba9a6fca")
Tasks created with the Tasks.insert method, this._id -> "57a128afbe5fd7e7ba9a6fca"

And the new remove method doesn't like the ObjectId part. How can I get just the ID? I would figure it'd be something like this._id._id, but that's undefined. The workaround was to remove the check from the "remove" method, which is less secure.

Link: https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/security-with-methods

Comment: When you insert from the console you'll always get an `ObjectId()` instead of a string unless you explicitly specify a string `_id` during the insert.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `this._id._str` to get the Hex part of the ObjectId.

I would suggest that your method only uses the string, and do a check in the client to see if you need to use this._id or this._id._str

Comment: Thank you! Is there something special about the underscores here? Or is it just a convention to name the properties with an underscore at the beginning? In python for example, sometimes _ or __ are used for the privacy of some attributes/methods - like telling other developers "Don't use these directly, they're meant to be hidden."

Comment: Actually where can I find out more about the objects I'm working with here? Like are there things I can use besides _id and _str? This isn't particularly helpful https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-ObjectID
Is there a place with some descriptions of what built in functions or objects I might run into? Hopefully with some examples? Like the Stripe api documentation was gorgeous when I worked with it in Python.

Comment: Underscore is just a convention. It implies internal, but there is nothing to stop you from using it. If you print the object to the console - console.log(this) - then you can inspect it to see what is in it. In Chrome and Firefox, press F12 to open the console.